# Dispatch task on main queue sync from custom serial queue

Tags: ios, multithreading, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I have come across a very interesting problem related to queue dead lock in iOS. Any way to avoid this?

Consider this:

1. Create a custom serial queue.
2. Dispatch some task (#1) on this serial queue asynchronously.
3. This async task (#1) on dispatches some task (#2) onto main queue sync.
4. Main queue dispatches some task (#3) onto serial queue sync.
5. Result - DeadLock

Below is the sample code for this.

- Since self.opQueue is a serial queue, task#3 will not start till task#1 completes.
- Since task#1 is calling main queue sync, so it will never complete till main queue completes task#2.
- Since main queue is waiting for opQueue to finish task#3, and opQueue is waiting for main queue to finish task#2 there is a deadlock.

  ```
  #import "ViewController.h"

  @interface ViewController ()
  @property(nonatomic,strong) dispatch_queue_t opQueue;
  @end

  @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    dispatch_queue_t queue =  dispatch_queue_create("com.tarun.sqqueue",
                                                 DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
    self.opQueue = queue;

    [self performOperations];
  }


  /// 1. Dispatch on serial queue async.
  /// 2. This async task on serial queue dispatchs some task onto 
  ///    main queue sync.
  /// 3. Main queue dispatched some task onto serial queue sync.
  /// 4. Result - DeadLock
  - (void)performOperations {

    /// task#1: Dispatch task on the serial Queue Asynchronously.
    /// So this is not blocking.
    dispatch_async(self.opQueue, ^{
      for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%d. Async on Serial Queue from Main Queue.",i);
      }

      /// task#2: Dispatching task on main queue synchronously from serial
      /// queue.So this queue will wait till main queue executes this task.(Blocking)
      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
          NSLog(@"%d. Sync on main queue from Serial Queue.",i);
        }
      });
    });

    /// task#3: Dispatching task on swrial queue synchronously from main
    /// queue.So main queue will wait till serial queue executes this task. (Blocking)
    dispatch_sync(self.opQueue, ^{
      for (int i = 1; i<=100; i++) {
        NSLog(@"%d. Sync on Serial Queue From Main Queue.",i);
      }
    });

    /// Since self.opQueue is a serial queue, task#3 will not start till task#1 completes.
    /// Since task#1 is calling main queue sync, 
    /// so it will never complete till main queue completes task#2.
    /// Since main queue is waiting for opQueue to finish task#3, and opQueue is waiting for main queue to finish task#2 there is a deadlock.

    NSLog(@"Back to main queue");
  }


  @end
  ```

Comment: Yes, don't do this. In particular dispatching sync tasks on serial queues that dispatch other tasks synchronously is asking for trouble unless you know which queues you are using

Comment: Here the Asynchronous task is dispatching synchronously. But I am not dispatching to the same queue synchronously ever. And let's say if custom serial queue is a part of a framework/library and exposed to be used by the app. Then framework doesn't have control over it, so how to avoid this?

Comment: But you are dispatching to the same queue； not directly, but that doesn't matter. It would generally not be the case that a framework would expose a queue for use by others. A framework may use a queue internally to manage a critical section or may accept a queue from the caller, but it would be a bad idea for a framework to provide a queue

Comment: Yes it is a hypothetical situation and ideally a framework would never expose the queue to used by outsiders but still theoretically it is possible and very easy to get into this deadlock. So I was just wondering it there any way we can avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

From Apple

> Important: You should never call the dispatch_sync or dispatch_sync_f
>   function from a task that is executing in the same queue that you are
>   planning to pass to the function. This is particularly important for
>   serial queues, which are guaranteed to deadlock, but should also be
>   avoided for concurrent queues.

Its a guaranteed dead lock. The only way to avoid this is to not implement it this way.